# Can I have each record start and end with a specific character in SQL*Plus?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to format output from a sql script as CSV. I'm going to be passing in the select statement as a parameter, so I can't really use the select clause to accomplish this. I've arrived at something that is fairly close:

```
set echo off
set feedback off
set wrap off
set newpage none
set pagesize 50000
set heading on
set underline off
set colsep '","'
set tab on
set trimspool on
set headsep off
set linesize 500
spool output.csv
```

This actually produces something close to what I'd like. The only missing quotes are the opening doublequote for the first column, and the closing doublequote for the last column.

Is there a way to do this with a sqlplus command?